# String to date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataset with dates encoded as strings formatted as %B %d, %Y, eg September 10, 2021.

Using:`df['sale_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.sale_date, format = '%B %d, %Y')`

produces this error `ValueError: time data 'September 10, 2021' does not match format '%B %d, %Y' (match)`

Manually checking with strptime`datetime.strptime('September 10, 2021', '%B %d, %Y')` produces the correct datetime object.

Is there something I missed in the pd.to_datetime?

Thanks.

Comment: I think there're some hidden characters with the string `September 10, 2021` in your df.  Fix those. For me your code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further investigation, I found out that the error only happens on the first element of the series. It seems that the string has '\ufeff' added to it. So I just did a `series.str.replace()` and now it is working. Sorry for the bother. Question is how did that BOM end up there?

Answer (score 0):

Very likely you have to eliminate some whitespaces first!

If I add whitespaces at the beginning, end or both..

```
datestring = ' September 10, 2021 '

datetime.datetime.strptime(datestring, '%B %d, %Y')
```

it will result in the same error message  as you have..

```
ValueError: time data ' September 10, 2021 ' does not match format '%B %d, %Y'
```

As a solution for a single value use:

```
datestring = ' September 10, 2021 '
datestring.strip()
```

for a column in a dataframe use:

```
dummy = pd.DataFrame(columns={'Date'}, data = [' September 10, 2021 ', ' September 11, 2021 ', ' September 12, 2021 '])
dummy.Date = dummy.Date.apply(lambda x: x.strip())
```